# SharedPreferences dont save

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

my problem: When I want to save a sharedPreference and restart the app, it doesnt load the right value..
My code:

```
int punkteint = 0;
TextView test1;
String points;
private static String SHARED_PREF_ID = "0";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    test1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test1);
    SharedPreferences load = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_ID, 0);
    points = load.getString("punkte", "0");
    points = SHARED_PREF_ID;
    test1.setText(points);
    mehrPunkte();
    }


public void mehrPunkte() {

    punkteint++;

    SHARED_PREF_ID = Integer.toString(punkteint);
    SharedPreferences load = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_ID, MODE_PRIVATE);
    points = load.getString("punkte", "0");
    points = SHARED_PREF_ID;
    test1.setText(points);

    SharedPreferences save = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_ID, MODE_PRIVATE);
    save.edit().putString("punkte", SHARED_PREF_ID).commit();
}
```

What did I do wrong here?
Hope you can help me

Comment: Why are you incrementing your Shared Preference ID each time you load and save preferences?

Comment: The question should be why are you saving everything in different files?

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
save.edit().putString("punkte", SHARED_PREF_ID).commit();
```

is saving SHARED_PREF_ID as the value of punkte.  So, it will always be 0.  Maybe you mean:

```
save.edit().putString("punkte", String.valueOf(punkteint)).commit();
```

or maybe:

```
save.edit().putString("punkte", String.valueOf(points)).commit();
```

I am not sure what you are trying to actually save.

Oh and you are resettiong the value as soonas you get it from the shared prefs:

```
points = load.getString("punkte", "0");
points = SHARED_PREF_ID;
```

Don't do the second line.

Comment: im trying to save punkteint. But your solution doesnt work... still "0"

Comment: where is it 0?  I mean you also reset the value you get from the shared preferences on the next line after you read it:points = load.getString("punkte", "0");
    points = SHARED_PREF_ID;

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you're trying to do here:

```
points = load.getString("punkte", "0");
points = SHARED_PREF_ID;
test1.setText(points);
```

Basically, what you've told it to do is "load `punkte`'s value into `points`, then load `SHARED_PREF_ID` into `points`". That means `points` will always be equal to `SHARED_PREF_ID` here. Remove the lines that say "`points = SHARED_PREF_ID;`" and you will probably have more success.

Additionally, I would not change `SHARED_PREF_ID`'s value. Make it a `final String` and give it some unique value (like `"punkte_prefs"`).

Lastly, I would take a look at [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) which has *great* examples, and @Kaediil's answer as well (as he caught something I missed...).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure. What your doing should work but I would use this instead

```
SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = save.edit();
prefEditor.putString("blah", blah);
PredEditor.commit()
```

Do the save in onPause and load in onResume. Could help if the data is meant to change thrpught the activity.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've gotten yourself all twisted up here.

```
  private static String SHARED_PREF_ID = "0";
  ...
  SharedPreferences load = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_ID, 0);
  points = load.getString("punkte", "0");
  points = SHARED_PREF_ID;
```

These lines read shared preferences from a file named "0". Is that what you wanted? That's a not-very-useful name for a file.  The next line reads a string value named "punkte" into the variable "points" and then immediately discards that value and replaces it with "0".

```
punkteint++;
SHARED_PREF_ID = Integer.toString(punkteint);
SharedPreferences load = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_ID, MODE_PRIVATE);
```

These lines increment a counter, use it to generate a whole new filename, and loads a whole new set of preferences from that file.  Again, you load "points" from those preferences and immediately discard the value, setting it to this new filename.

```
SharedPreferences save = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_ID, MODE_PRIVATE);
save.edit().putString("punkte", SHARED_PREF_ID).commit();
```

These lines re-load the preferences from that new file again and writes the filename into the "punkte" value.

It looks like you're deliberately generating a series of preferences files, each of which contains its own name under the value "punkte".

When you next run the app, you'll go back to reading preferences from file "0", getting the same value you got the first time: "0"

It would help if you told us what you were actually trying to do.